# How to compile and run Java project from GitHub

Tags: java, git, github

The following link
https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Build-Instructions attempts to explain how to compile and run projects, but it did not work for me (I could not get Ant to run). Is there any way to compile and run a Java project without using Ant? Or is there any other way for to compile and run a Java project?

I'm running Mac OS X Yosemite, I also have NetBeans. Since I'm a newbie please try to be specific.

UPDATE: The instructions to install Ant (from the site) were too confusing, I tried using (I already isntalled Homebrew) `brew install ant` on terminal, but I get an error that says:

> cannot write to usr/local/Cellar

Comment: As far as I know Ant is a Java build tools that you need it because this project is based on Ant. It's what you need for this project only not all projects in Git repositories.

Comment: *"I get an error that says, cannot write to usr/local/Cellar"*.  Is that an Ant error or an error in the wrapper script?  Show us the relevant parts of the "build.xml" file.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to get Ant to run.

There is no generic way to do everything that an Ant `build.xml` file says to do.  In some cases, it could be a specifying a simple sequence of steps using `javac`, `jar` and so on.  In other cases, it could be doing complicated things that are impossible to do without "programming" at some level.

As far as your specific problem is concerned, I can't see the "build.xml" file, so I can't advise on whether building without using Ant is feasible.  (It isn't advisable ....)

---

If you explained what you mean by "I could not get ant to run", perhaps someone could help you with addressing your problem ... the right way.